# angular.js data only shows most recent reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to have multiple text elements, dynamically added through a function, keyed to always display the contents of an input text field.  Instead, the bound text only shows up on the most recently added text element, and all others disappear(?).  Even the original span tag written in the body that I'm referencing no longer updates to the user-supplied data (not that you can tell this last part in the below example because it's hidden).

w3school code run here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GD4AV18UABPF

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>

  <div ng-app="">
 <script>
    function linkPairing() {
        var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('.transaction'));
        var $hidden = angular.element(document.querySelector('.hiddenNodeName'));

        divElement.append($hidden);
        divElement.append("<br />");
    }   
  </script>

  <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
  <form>
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="newNodeName"></p>
  <p>{{newNodeName}}</p>
  <p>{{newNodeName}}</p>
  <button class="addNewTransaction" id="addNewTransaction" type="button" onclick="linkPairing()">Go</button>                
  </form>
  <div hidden><span class="hiddenNodeName" >{{newNodeName}}</span></div>
  <p class="transaction"></p>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I realize this hidden tag approach used to add the bound data reference may be unconventional, and, according to other questions, displayed references might usually be generated by something like:

```
var $div = $("<span>{{newNodeName}}</span>");
divElement.append($compile($div)($scope));
$scope.$apply();
```

I tried variations of above, but was not able to get even the partial success seen in the example.  I suspect I need a greater understanding of angular, particularly scope, to be successful with this approach.  I'm using both jquery and angular, and read stackOverflow's opinion to keep js module loads to a minimum.  Originally everything was in jquery, but the ng-bind data in angular looked very appealing when I got to this particular functionality of having linked data display. I'm reluctant to refactor everything into angular.js just now with the uncertainty that I'll be successful in the end. Can this work-around be made to function as I expected?

Comment: Have you tried an approach using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I haven't, no, but looking at it now it looks like it's used for displaying a set, one right after another.  That might be what's happening in my code snippet, but in the actual page there are potentially a number of different forks of dynamic additions the user could choose to add to the form, some that don't involve the node name input box at all.  Are you suggesting something like pushing all the dynamic adds into an array, and reprinting the page from this array using nb-repeat whenever the user-supplied content changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working example :https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GD4KGYTO3RCF

and also a snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <!--module starts surrounds body tag name is myapp -->
  <body ng-app="myapp">
  <!--controller surrounds the  div tag ,A controller is associated with module for functionality purpose-->
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
  <form >
  Input something in the input box <br><br>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="newNodeName">
  <!-- we use ng click  for click in angular js -->
  <button  id="btn-newTransation" type="button"                  
  ng-click="linkPairing()">Go</button>
  
  </form>
  <!-- ng-repeat repeats the html inside it , nodes is array, node is each iteration's value , track by $index to avoid duplication error and get index
  ng-repeat="node in nodes"
  -->
  <!--ng repeat usually expects array but to just repeat an element some time this will work as shortcut-->
  <div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(count) track by $index" class="nodes">
   <p>{{newNodeName}}</p>
  </div>
  {{message}}
  <!-- i dont know why are you using following tags for -->
  <div hidden>
  <span class="hiddenNodeName">{{newNodeName}}</span></div>
  <p class="transaction"></p>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    //initializing the myapp with controller
    angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("myctrl",function($scope){
    //variables in $scope are accessible in html example inside interpolation {{newNodeName}}
     $scope.message="";
    $scope.count=0;
 $scope.linkPairing=function(){ 
     $scope.count++;
     if($scope.count==3){
       $scope.message="Did it work? if it worked please upvote and mark it as correct "
  }
     }
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you want to see thought and what "state" you get from my code?

Comment: My response didn't fit in a comment, so I made it an answer.  Additionally though, I notice that you included an "ng-controller", which I don't understand yet.  Is that maybe a key piece of a solution?  I also have to look at whether ng-click is different from onclick.

Comment: yeah!  that's it!

Comment: Yes, this works for the test case I gave where the same text element gets repeated.  Thank you, Supercool.  I have a better sense now of the ng-repeat function you and Anurag are noting.  Does this work over what I had because the ng-repeat div tags are all generated at the same time, because the ng-repeat div is within the html portion instead of generated tags in javascript, or maybe because you've used angular fully w/ a controller and $scope?  Do you think I could take what you've done and use it in cases where the generated tags and intermittent among other generated tags?

Answer (score 0):

[responding to Supercool's answer, which didn't fit in a comment:]

That's closer than what I had, and gives me a good start on an array solution (thank you, Supercool).  Not quite what I was after though.  Here's the states I get from your code:

```
[State 1., after typing "1st" and pressing Go]
input box: 1st
1st

[State 2. after adding "2nd," and pressing Go]
input box: 1st 2nd
1st
1st 2nd

[End State. after adding "3rd," and pressing Go]
input box: 1st 2nd 3rd
1st
1st 2nd
1st 2nd 3rd
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
[State 1., after typing "1st" and pressing Go]
input box: 1st
1st

[State 2. after adding "2nd," and pressing Go]
input box: 1st 2nd
1st 2nd
1st 2nd

[End State. after adding "3rd," and pressing Go]
input box: 1st 2nd 3rd
1st 2nd 3rd
1st 2nd 3rd
1st 2nd 3rd
```

Additionally, after every state of keys being pressed inbetween pressing "Go," all generated text would mirror whatever is in the input box.  Including all of these inbetween states for the example above, the penultimate one would be:

```
[Penultimate state. in the middle of typing out "3rd" and before pressing Go]
input box: 1st 2nd 3r
1st 2nd 3r
1st 2nd 3r
```

I thought I could get this kind of functionality because I thought (still do?) that angular's {{reference}}s linked to the original, and would automatically update no matter how many of them you had, when you made them, etc..

Comment: Ive changed the answer , Check it